# Turn based multiplayer: createMatch() returns false task

Tags: android, google-play-games, turn

When I call `createMatch()` on `TurnBasedMultiplayerClient` the task that it returns is `false(task.isSuccessful)` and the exception I get is `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 26502: CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED`.
The documentation says that the GoogleApiClient is is in an inconsistent state but how do I reconnect it? I don't have a `GoogleAPiClient` object so I can't just call `GoogleAPiClient.reconnect()`.

I'm using the default ui for selecting players:

```
private fun onStartMatchClicked() {
    val allowAutoMatch = true
    mTurnBasedMultiplayerClient = Games.getTurnBasedMultiplayerClient(this@MultiplayerActivity, clientAccount!!)
    mTurnBasedMultiplayerClient!!.getSelectOpponentsIntent(1, 1, allowAutoMatch)
        .addOnSuccessListener { intent -> startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS) }
}
```

Here's the onActivityResult method:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == RC_SELECT_PLAYERS) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            finish()
            return
        }
        val invitees = data!!.getStringArrayListExtra(Games.EXTRA_PLAYER_IDS)

        // Get automatch criteria
        var autoMatchCriteria: Bundle? = null


        val minAutoPlayers = data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0)
        val maxAutoPlayers = data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0)

        autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(minAutoPlayers,
            maxAutoPlayers, 0)
        val tbmc = TurnBasedMatchConfig.builder()
            .addInvitedPlayers(invitees)
            .setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria).build()
        mTurnBasedMultiplayerClient!!.createMatch(tbmc).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) { //this is where I get the exception
                    match = task.result
                } else {
                    // There was an error. Show the error.
                    var status = CommonStatusCodes.DEVELOPER_ERROR
                    val exception = task.exception
                    if (exception is ApiException) {
                        val apiException = exception as ApiException?
                        status = apiException!!.statusCode
                    }
                    handleError(status, exception)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you happen to figure out what the problem was? I'm having this problem with real time multiplayer. I'm able to sign in and access achievements and leaderboards, but I'm having the same problem you are with the multiplayer.

Comment: I wasn't really able to figure out what the problem was, but I created a new project in the Google API& Services platform and in Google Play Console, connected the two projects again, and the problem just dissappiered. Maybe I used an API unnecessarily or created an unnecessary and that caused the problem. I recommend you to check the API&Services platform and only use the API-s that you need and create only credentials that you need.

Comment: So I've found the problem was that I was using my upload key (since I'm using google play app signing.) Right now the only way I can test my code is by creating an internal release, which is pretty annoying. I'm trying to figure it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56065375/testing-games-services-using-upload-key-instead-of-google-play-app-signing-key Thanks for your response.